# Can timer function be used to simulate other function after every 60 min?

Tags: matlab, timer, infinite-loop

In my code I need to simulate my matlab code after every 60 minutes for 2 days. I have to retrieve a particular data from a url. Currently I have figured out how to do that.

```
     xdom = xmlread('http://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/?lat=53.05;lon=4.8;msl=1');
cloudtags = xdom.getElementsByTagName('cloudiness');
cloudiness = cell(cloudtags.getLength, 2); 
for item = 1 : cloudtags.getLength
   cloudtag = cloudtags.item(item - 1);
   timetag = cloudtag.getParentNode.getParentNode;
   cloudiness{item, 1} = char(timetag.getAttribute('from'));
   cloudiness{item, 2} = str2double(cloudtag.getAttribute('percent'));
end
cloudiness;
 matchrow = strcmp(cloudiness(:, 1), '2015-03-12T15:00:00Z');
cloud = cloudiness{matchrow, 2};
```

Now I need to do this iteration every 60 min, so that I can store this data in a separate file each time. Can someone help me with how to do it with the help of timer function or with some other function?

Comment: and you haven't tried the [**`timer`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/use-a-matlab-timer-object.html) function? If so, what didn't work?

Comment: I understood that timer function might work. But I am really new to the matlab, I am still trying to figure out how to run the code with timer function. And on top of that I want to build a code that each time the timer function runs, it saves the output of the code mentioned in a different filename.